# How to change the author name that appears in comments on Word for Mac?

Tags: mac, office-365, macos

How do I change the author name that appears in comments on Microsoft Word for Mac? I'm using Mac OS 14 and Word from Microsoft Office 365 version 16.8

I've tried Preferences > User Info > Name and then restarting but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate this on Mac OS Sonoma 14.2.1 and Word version 16.82.

You'll need to check the *Always use this name regardless of how I'm signed into Office* checkbox to do what you want. Please note that older comments in the file won't be changed retroactively - only those you make after the settings change.

[image: Screenshot of Word's 'User Information' dialog box, showing 'Your Name' in the Name field, 'YN' in the Initials field, and with the Always use this name regardless of how I'm signed into Office checkbox checked and annotated with a red square around it]